# Consent Management Script must be on first place, how to do this?

Tags: magento2

as most of you know, it is now mandatory to have a Consent Managment Tool where visitors can decide f.e. whether they accept Google Analytics or not.

I have a tool for this but do have one problem implementing it into the pages.
The script must be the first at all to work properly.

I tried several things, but Magento is inserting the google-analytics/analytics.js always at the top of the page. Therefore as well before the script from my consent management tool.

This happens if I set "Move JS to bottom" to true, as well if I set it to false.

In any case google script is before my consent management script.

As I think somebody from you must have the same or similar problem, I hope that somebody has an idea how to fix this.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Best regards
Chequille

PS: using Magento 2.3.5-p1